# How to make a radio button disappear in a section with 4 radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this in my HTML:

```
<div class="field">
        @Html.RadioButton("button1", id1, new { @id = "button1", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button1" class="radio">Label1</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("button2", id2, new { @id = "button2", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button2" class="radio">Label2</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("button3", id3, new { @id = "button3", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button3" class="radio">Label3</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("button4", id4, new { @id = "button4", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button4" class="radio">Label4</label>
    </div>
```

and I want to make one of those disappear, in some of the cases I receive, so it appears like

```
<div class="field">
        @Html.RadioButton("button1", id1, new { @id = "button1", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button1" class="radio">Label1</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("button2", id2, new { @id = "button2", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button2" class="radio">Label2</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("button3", id3, new { @id = "button3", @class = "radio" })
        <label for="button3" class="radio">Label3</label>
    </div>
```

but of course I can't make two copies and show the copy I want, because then I would have some buttons with same ids and I want to work with them in my .js afterwards.

The question is: Is there a way to make the button I want disappear from the view without destroying the view? (I tried to insert the radio button into a div and then "hiding" (.hide() method in javascript) it when I wanted, but it didn't look well when it had to appear.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the radio button, rather than putting it in a DIV?

Comment: Well that's exactly what I am looking for, how do I do that?

Comment: Assuming you're using jQuery, `$('#button4').hide()`.

Comment: what is the actual problem? do you want the layout somehow changed / or not / when hiding the radio?

Comment: It hides the button, now I'm trying to find how to hide the label ^^. I will ask again if I can't find it (I hope I'm not as useless as with the button), thanks!

Comment: @fast, no, I just want to hide/show the button and it's label

Comment: It took me some amount of time, but I finally found it... setting document.querySelector("label[for='buttonId']").style.display = "none" works